# How to hide SQL statements from hackers?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I want to hide my DB connection details from hackers when they view source code 
as they can send malicious code to my DB.

For example:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The hacker now knows what the user and password and name of my database is and he can inject my DB with bad code. I searched the site but couldn't find the right format to address my question.

Comment: If hackers can view your source code, they can read your password too, they can read your salts, your encryption keys and everything else that makes any kind of security viable. Visitors should not be able to see your source code. period.

Comment: You could define the username and password, then store them in a file not in your website directory, if you are really that worried about someone seeing php.

Comment: If everything is alright, users can't see your PHP source code, although it's a good practice to place your credentials outside of the web root and `include` them when needed.

Comment: User can't see php code (unless your server is misconfigured). Thus, having your database password inside your PHP code do not make it available to hackers.

Comment: Your hacker is not supposed to access files on your server, he is not supposed to see your php source in your server, there should be a security around your server to prevent that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @vascowhite i just asked about hide connection details

Comment: @FritsvanCampen how can u advice me ? any soultions

Comment: @MarcelKorpel but if i included them are they still shown when hacker click view source from browser?

Comment: @TheSniper104 The view source option in your browser shows the HTML markup of the page. Not the PHP code that generated the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php is a server-side language and cannot be read by others unless they have the php file what users see in the browser is the output parsed by the browser.

as long as you don't echo, print or in any way display yoour credentials you should be good.

Comment: i mean when i write html form and sql statement in the same page when user click view source from browser he is able to see it

Comment: if the code is enclosed in php tags it cannot be viewed by the view source option

Comment: No problem, it was something i wondered when i first started to learn to use databases with php.

Answer (score 1):

They can't read the database information unless they really hacked or cracked to your web account. You can encode the database info but that's about it.

The correct approach would be to prevent access to the PHP code itself. Having the database information in an [included](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) file only read & writable by the web server would prevent foul access. The downside to this is that you need root/admin account to update the information should you need to change it.

To prevent SQL injection, you should use real_escape_string for strings and is_numeric for numbers.

Comment: No, to prevent SQL injection one should use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel That's another, probably easier option. Thanks for adding.